# shiny app only works on specific browsers / platforms

Tags: shiny, rstudio

I have programmed a shiny app in RStudio using R version 3.2.4. The app can be found here: https://koenvandenberge.shinyapps.io/tempConditioning/
Note that there is quite a lot of data to be loaded so it takes a couple of seconds to load.

I have deployed it on my Macbook and it seems as if it only works on Safari and Chromium browsers. It does not seem to work on Chrome or Firefox browsers. With this I mean that the plots which should be generated are not. The drop-down menu is present as it should be, so the app does not crash, but the plots that should be generated by selecting something from the drop-down menu do not.

Is there any way to fix this? You can find the code of my app below:

```
library(shiny)
library(scales)
load("countMatrix.RData")
countMatrixAllSub = as.data.frame(countMatrix$counts[,-1]) ; rm(countMatrix)
sampleNames = unlist(lapply(strsplit(colnames(countMatrixAllSub),split=".",fixed=TRUE), function(x) x[4]))
sampleNames[28] <- "3c0a"
treat=substr(sampleNames,2,2)
time=substr(sampleNames,3,nchar(sampleNames)-1)
timeC=as.numeric(time)
timeC[timeC==15]=0.25

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Gene expression: conditioning experiment Gust"),

   # Sidebar with a
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         selectInput("gene",
                     "Pick a gene",
                      choices = rownames(countMatrixAllSub))
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("genePlot")
      )
   )
))

# Define server logic required to draw an expression plot
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$genePlot <- renderPlot({
    par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 3, 1))
    plot(y=countMatrixAllSub[input$gene,],x=timeC, col=c("black","red")[as.numeric(factor(treat))], pch=19,cex=.6,xaxt="n",xlab="Time", ylab="Expression")
    lines(x=unique(timeC[!timeC==0]),y=colMeans(sapply(unique(timeC[!timeC==0]), function(t) as.matrix(countMatrixAllSub[input$gene,treat=="c" & timeC==t]))), col=1)
    lines(x=unique(timeC[!timeC==0]),y=colMeans(sapply(unique(timeC[!timeC==0]), function(t) as.matrix(countMatrixAllSub[input$gene,treat=="t" & timeC==t]))), col=2)
    axis(1,at=c(0,0.25,1,3,6,9),labels=c("","15m","1h","3h","6h","9h"))
    abline(v=c(0,0.25,1,3,6,9),col=alpha("grey",.6))
    mtext("Conditioned",side=3, adj=0,col="red")
    mtext("Unconditioned",side=3, adj=0.2, col="black")
  })
})

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "doesn't work"

Comment: @Dason    I have added this to my question: With this I mean that the plots which should be generated are not. The drop-down menu is present as it should be, so the app does not crash, but the plots that should be generated by selecting something from the drop-down menu do not.